# Modular Congruence, Power

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

$(3x^2+2x+1)(4x^3+x^2+5x+1)=5x^5+4x^4+1\equiv 1 \pmod {x^4}$

Expanding the first part, I get $12x^5+11x^4+21x^3+14x^2+7x+1$. However, I do not understand how to get from the above statement to $5x^5+4x^4+1\equiv 1 \pmod{x^4}$.

Another example:
$(2x+1)(2x^2+x+1)= 4x^3+4x^2+3x+1 \equiv 1 \pmod {x^2}$.

Any help with understanding this concept would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Additional Note: (Not sure if this helps at all)

The original question involves Newton's Iteration.
Let $a=5x^5 + 4x^4 + 3x^3 + 2x^2 + x$ and $b = x^2 + 2x + 3$ be polynomials. Then the inverse of the reversal of b, multiplied by the reversal of b, must $\equiv 1 mod x^4$.

Comment: The first will be true if done mod $\,7.\ $ Are you working mod $\,7\,$ too?

Comment: Similarly, the 2nd is true if done mod $3.\ $

Comment: Thanks for your rely! Though 7 and 3 do work, I'm not certain if I can use specific examples to dismiss powers below 4 and 2 respectively. 

For the first example, I'm also not exactly sure how the textbook/notes got from the first part to the second. 12x^5 changes to 5x^5 and 11x^4 changes to 4x^4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first congruence is true $\iff 7\,(3x^3\!+2x^2\!+x)\equiv 0 \pmod{x^4}.\, $ To further deduce that it's $\equiv 0$ you need further hypothesis, $ $ e.g. $\ 7\equiv 0.\,$ Lacking such the claim is false.

Similary, the second congruence holds $\iff 3x\equiv 0\pmod{x^2},\ $ e.g. if $\ 3\equiv 0.$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'll look more into my question, and other examples.

Comment: Update, the OP gave further detail in a [subsequent question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1158043/242) (now deleted) that reveals that the first congruence is on $\,\Bbb F_7[x],\,$ so, indeed, $\,7\equiv 0.\ \ $

Comment: ^ I understand now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @nomnom Great, happy (Newton) iterating...